# custom button using android studio

Tags: android, xml

when in my drawable layout (custom_button), codes are correct and the shape along with color pop on screen but when I use it in my activity layout (interface of my first page of app), the corners are good but the color I chose was not applied even though my code is correct.
this is my code:

```
<solid android:color="#00FFDD"/>

<corners android:radius="20sp"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a material theme, the button will have a tint that will change the button's background color.

You can simply remove the tint by adding this line to your button's xml code in your activity :

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"
```

Comment: @JeanAttieh Happy to help. Btw here in stackOverflow , the preferred way of saying 'thanks' is by  accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask.